# How to interpret Forecasting Models

Tags: r, model, forecasting, arima

I created a forecasting model using forecast for a period of 5 years and autoplot.

What does the colouring mean i.e. what does the grey area and purplish area indicate? Also the blue line?

[image]

Comment: Please read: [forecasting principles and practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/).

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it appears to focus on data analysis or statistics and not a practical programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we obtain a forecast, we are estimating the middle of the range of possible values the random variable could take. Often, a forecast is accompanied by a prediction interval giving a range of values the random variable could take with relatively high probability. For example, a 95% prediction interval contains a range of values which should include the actual future value with probability 95%.

[Recommended reading on Forecasting](https://otexts.com/fpp3/perspective.html)